# Github on-schedule action workflow executes in delay or not at all

Tags: python-3.x, github, workflow, github-actions

I have 2 workflows inside my repository - one that is a CI that runs on each push and one that is supposed to execute a script on a scheduled time.

The scheduled workflow looks like that:

```yaml
name: scheduled-run

on:
  schedule:
    # UTC time
    - cron: "45 14 1,15,30 * *"

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.7
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.7
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - name: Execute python script
      env:
        TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN }}
        TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID }}
        AWS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_KEY_ID }}
        AWS_SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_KEY }}
      run: |
        python cci.py -r
```

No matter how and to when I set the cron schedule - the workflow does not start! Sometimes it would start way after the supposed time but mostly it does not start. I have tried to recreate the workflow from scratch but it doesn't seem to help. What's going on here?

Comment: When do you expect it to run? And when did it actually run? (Specific date / time)

Comment: @riQQ I expect it to run just like it says on the cron notation - at 14:45 UTC at each 1st, 15th and 30th of each month. Since today is 1.1.2021 it should have been run. Like I wrote - sometimes it does not run at all, sometimes it runs 20 minutes after, sometimes more, but most of the times it's just not running at all.

Comment: Based on how long some workflows take to even start for `on-push` or `on-pull_request` events, I suspect GitHub's datacenters are frequently overloaded for Actions runs. It's been particularly bad in the past 4ish weeks.

Comment: Is this committed to master?

Comment: @DannyB Yes, this is committed to master.

Comment: Well the workflow runs but still not point on time - it can be delayed for minutes or hours without clear order.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your workflow with slightly changed cron

```yaml
name: scheduled-run

on:
  schedule:
    # UTC time
    - cron: "55 13,14,15 1,4,15,30 * *"

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.7
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.7
```

And it works as expected:

[image]

Please try with sth smaller (like above) and with slightly different cron so you would not wait long to verify your changes.

Comment: What do you mean by "sth"?

Comment: Something  There is no clear reason why this doesn't work for you. So best what can we do it's to start with minimal example.